# Adding global error on any field error in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am using Struts2 and a bunch of Validation with Annotations. How do I add a global error message as well on top of field validation errors. Thanks, Fedor

Answer (score 1):

An action has a collection called `fieldErrors` as well as a collection called `actionErrors`.  I can't remember if its in the base class `ActionSupport`, but you can try the method `addActionError(String message)` and then it will be available along with any field errors.

Keep in mind that action errors are **separate** from field errors and kept in a different collection.  The field errors are in a Map so the UI can match up the error with the field name where as the action errors are just a List I think.

I think there are two UI tags `<s:fielderrors/> and <s:actionerrors/>`  but you should check the Struts2 tag reference.